# multiple variable for if else statement

Tags: java

I have written some code to check if the user has entered a number between 1 and 5, and now I would also like my code to allow the user to enter the letters A, S, D or M.

Is there a way to combine the code where I can have it identify whether the user has entered 1-5 or A, S, D, M?

How do I edit the code below so the user can enter either an Integer or a character? Do I have to write a snippet of code underneath the loop for it to identify that a user did not enter 1-5 but did enter A, S, D, or M, as in break out of the loop? Or is it a separate loop all together. I am so confused!

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Selection {
    Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    int selectionOne() {
        int inputInt;
        do { //do loop will continue to run until user enters correct response
            System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5, A for Addition, S for subtraction, M for multiplication, or D for division: ");
            try { 
                inputInt = readInput.nextInt(); //user will enter a response
                if (inputInt >= 1 && inputInt <=5) {
                    System.out.print("Thank you");
                    break; //user entered a number between 1 and 5
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, you have not entered the correct number, please try again.");
                }
                continue;
            }
            catch (final InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Try again.");
                readInput.nextLine(); // discard non-int input
                continue; // loop will continue until correct answer is found
            }
        } while (true);
        return inputInt;
    } 
}
```

Comment: If your input can be a letter, but you define your input field as an int, what do you suppose is going to happen? Do you expect your users to input an ASCII code? Hint: String + parse.

Comment: i am very new to this, can you please further explain how to work the string into this? thanks

Comment: Have any of the answers helped you?

Comment: yes the answer are very helpful in helping me understand how to put it together. But now i need to call this code onto another class as a While code. I'm guessing this is not correct.while ((inputOperation = mySelection.selectionOne()) != 5)

Comment: @userQuestion Now it returns a String. You could try: `while (!(inputOperation = mySelection.selectionOne()).equals("5"))`

Comment: oh yay! it worked. Thanks! onto the next part of the project. it has taken me quite a few days to write a calculator. i am a total beginner at java. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of using an `int` input, just use a `String` input and convert it to an integer when you need to. You can use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to convert a `String` to an `int`.

So when you check if the input is valid, you need to check if the input is equal to `"A"`, `"S"`, `"M"` or `"D"`, or any values from 1-5 when it is converted to an `int`.

So to check if it's one of the characters, you could do this:

```
if (input.equals("A") || input.equals("S") || input.equals("M") || input.equals("D"))
```

And then to test if it's an `int` of value 1 through 5, you could do this:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(input) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(input) <= 5)
```

Just parse the input to an `int` and then check the range as you already have done.

The return type of this method will be `String` now, instead of `int`. If you need it to be an `int` for whatever reason, you can just parse the value to an `int` and then return that instead. But I just returned it as a `String`.

The last thing I changed was the `catch` block. Now, instead of an `InputMismatchException` (because they can enter `String`s now, I changed it to `NumberFormatException`, which would happen if a `String` that could not be converted to an `int` was attempted to be. For example, `Integer.parseInt("hello")` will throw a `NumberFomatException` because `"hello"` can not be represented as an integer. But, `Integer.parseInt("1")` would be fine and would return `1`.

Note that you should test the `String` equivalence first so that you don't  go into your `block` before you have a chance to test all conditions you need to.

The method would look like this:

```
String selectionOne() {
    String input;
    do { //do loop will continue to run until user enters correct response
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5, A for Addition, S for subtraction, M for multiplication, or D for division: ");
        try { 
            input = readInput.nextLine(); //user will enter a response
            if (input.equals("A") || input.equals("S") || input.equals("M") || input.equals("D")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                break; //user entered a character of A, S, M, or D
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(input) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(input) <= 5) { 
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                break; //user entered a number between 1 and 5
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you have not entered the correct number, please try again.");
            }
            continue;
        }
        catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Try again.");
            continue; // loop will continue until correct answer is found
        }
    } while (true);
    return input;
}
```

Comment: @userQuestion Great. If you feel that I've properly answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @MarsAtomic mentioned, first thing you should change your input to `String` instead of an `int` so you can easily handle both characters and digits.

Change:

```
int inputInt;
```

To:

```
String input;
```

Then change:

```
inputInt = readInput.nextInt();
```

To:

```
input = readInput.next();
```

To accommodate reading `String` instead of `int`.

Now you reach at 2 main cases (and 2 subcases):

```
1) input is a single character
   a) input is a single digit from 1-5
   b) input is a single character from the set ('A', 'S', 'D', 'M')
2) input is an error value
```

Also, since you are not calling `Scanner.nextInt`, you don't need to use the `try/catch` statement and can print your errors in `else` blocks.

Furthermore, you should have your method return a `char` or a `String` instead of an `int` so you can return both `1-5` or `A,S,D,M`. I will assume you want to return a `char`. If you want to return a `String` instead, you can `return input` instead of `return val` in the code bellow.

**NOTE:** *The code bellow can be simplified and shortened, I just added variables and comments in an attempt to make each step clear to what is being read or converted. You can look at @mikeyaworski's answer for a more concise way of doing this.*

Here is how your code could look like:

```
   char selectionOne() {
        String input;
        do {
            input = readInput.next();
            // check if input is a single character
            if(input.length() == 1) {
                char val = input.charAt(0);
                // check if input is a single digit from 1-5
                if(Character.isDigit(val)) {
                    int digit = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    if (digit >= 1 && digit <=5) {
                        System.out.print("Thank you");
                        return val; // no need to break, can return the correct digit right here
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you have not entered the correct number, please try again.");
                    }
                } else {
                    // check if input is in our valid set of characters
                    if(val == 'A' || val == 'S' || val == 'M' || val == 'D') { 
                        System.out.print("Thank you");
                        return val;  // return the correct character
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you have not entered the correct character, please try again.");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you have not entered the correct input format, please try again.");
            }
        } while(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input can be both characters and letters, why not change to looking for a char or String? Then, you can look for "1" or "A" without any trouble.

Comment: Is there an echo in here?

Comment: how can i modify it so it looks for the string or char? i am very new to this and this is very difficult for me to understand. thanks

Comment: Oops. I didn't even look at the comments. I'll remove, and you can answer.

Comment: @VinceEmigh It wasn't an answer because I would rather hint at a way for him to solve his own problems (thereby learning something) rather than reaching for low hanging fruit in order to generate rep. Some day, I might find myself standing next to him in a scrum, and I'd prefer a higher degree of critical thinking.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I do not think he was referring to the quality of your hint. I think he was referring to you putting your hint in a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @MarsAtomic He put his strategy into an answer because he doesn't have enough rep to even comment. There's nothing unique about your hint, so it's not like he stole the idea from you anyway.